# How to replace multiple spaces with single space?

Tags: c#, regex

I am developing web app using C#. I want to replace multiple spaces with single space in between string. I tried with normal string replace function, but it was not helpful. It is possible with Regular Expression, but I don't have clear idea about that. Please provide a example code for the following string:

Actual String:

```
Have       a   Nice              Day !  !!
```

Needed:

```
Have a Nice Day !!!
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Have a nice day ! !!`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can match the following:

`@"\s+"`

and replace with:

`" "`

```
Regex.Replace("Have       a   Nice              Day !  !!", @"\s+", " ");
```

Answer (score 5):

See if there are two or more spaces exist, if so replace it with single space.

```
var subject = "Have       a   Nice              Day !  !!";
var result = Regex.Replace(subject,@"\s{2,}"," ");
```